# TransactionID field of BootP/DHCP - random generated once or every time?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, dhcp, bootp

I have to work with a device sending BootP request with the same TransactionID every time, since [DHCP RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) says that

> "    xid           4  Transaction ID, a random number chosen by the
>                       client, used by the client and server to associate
>                       messages and responses between a client and a
>                       server."

Does it mean that TransactionID is generated randomly once and use it forever or it shoul be generated randomly on every BootP Request?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Transaction ID in DHCP packets can be changed.

You can observe it even in the pair of DHCP Discovery and Request.